# Combination of data entry and drop down selections into a js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a data input section in my page, in which user will have to put his/her name into a blank space and then make a selection between yes/no dropdown options. Once is filled out user clicks 'Generate" and all the information, questions and answers, appears beneath. How do I manage for the js to consider both open ended and dropdown questions/answers into the results? and How do I resize the font of the results? This is what I have so far..

```
<form name="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <font size="3">
        <label for="q7">- Done it?</label>
    </font>
    <select id="q7">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="populateResults()" value="Generate">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
    <script>
function populateResults() {
  var selects = document.forms.myForm.querySelectorAll('select'),
      result = document.getElementById("result");
  Array.from(selects).forEach(function(a, i) {
      var answer = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text,
          question = selects[i].labels[0].textContent;
      result.innerHTML += question + ' ' + answer + '
            <br>';
  })
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for your `option` in the select, it should have a `value` property.

You are way overcomplicating the code.

You can just do this:

```
<form name="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<font size="3">
    <label for="q7">- Done it?</label>
</font>
<select id="q7">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="populateResults()" value="Generate">
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function populateResults() {
    var select = $('#q7').val();
    var name = $('#firstname').val();
    var result = name + ' - Done it? ' + select;
    $('#result').text(result);
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty verbose but here I added some id's, removed the code from the markup, added a class to the label so I could both find an style it:

Revised markup:

```
<form id="myform" name="myForm">Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <label for="q7" class="mylabel">- Done it?</label>
    <select id="q7">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Generate" id="generate" />
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Add this CSS (removed the obsolete font tag)

```
.mylabel {
    font-size:1.5em;
}
```

VERBOSE code (clean it up, verbose to make the intent obvious)

```
function populateResults() {
    var myselect = $('#q7');
    var selectedText = myselect.find('option:selected').text();
    var selectedVal = myselect.val();
    var question = myselect[0].labels[0].textContent;//same thing
    question = myselect.siblings('.mylabel').text();// same thing
    $('#result').append(question + ' :' + selectedText + ":" + selectedVal + '<br />');
}
$('#myform').on('click', '#generate', populateResults);
```